# Mozilla Firefox Add-on Android - Page Action not working

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, mozilla, add-on

I have been working on this issue for a few hours now and can't seem to find any good sources on how to implement page action on android. Just the same one, [Differences_between_desktop_and_Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Differences_between_desktop_and_Android).

I hooked up my app to the web debugger in firefox get no errors. I tried to manually call some functions and none were defined. I could be doing it wrong, but it works on my PC version of Firefox.

I created some context menu items at the top of my BG script. I'm not sure if that would affect the execution of the script on android.

```
ReferenceError: browser is not defined[Learn More] debugger eval code:1:1
```

Below is the code the creates the Page Action which is included in my `Background.js.`

```
/* *********** */
/* Page Action */
/* *********** */
const TITLE_APPLY = "Stack Open";
const TITLE_REMOVE = "Stack Closed";
const APPLICABLE_PROTOCOLS = ["http:", "https:"];

/*
Based on the current title, Update the page action's title and icon to reflect its state.
*/
function toggleT(tab) {

  function gotTitle(title) {
    if (title === TITLE_APPLY) {
      console.log(tab.id);
      //browser.pageAction.setIcon({tabId: tab.id, path: "pressed.svg"});
      browser.pageAction.setTitle({tabId: tab.id, title: TITLE_REMOVE});
    } else {
      //browser.pageAction.setIcon({tabId: tab.id, path: "nPressed.svg"});
      browser.pageAction.setTitle({tabId: tab.id, title: TITLE_APPLY});
    }
  }

  var gettingTitle = browser.pageAction.getTitle({tabId: tab.id});
  gettingTitle.then(gotTitle);
}

/*
Returns true only if the URL's protocol is in APPLICABLE_PROTOCOLS.
*/
function protocolIsApplicable(url) {
  var anchor =  document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = url;
  return APPLICABLE_PROTOCOLS.includes(anchor.protocol);
}

/*
Initialize the page action: set icon and title, then show.
Only operates on tabs whose URL's protocol is applicable.
*/
function initializePageAction(tab) {
  if (protocolIsApplicable(tab.url)) {
    browser.pageAction.setIcon({tabId: tab.id, path: "../books.png"});
    browser.pageAction.setTitle({tabId: tab.id, title: TITLE_APPLY});
    browser.pageAction.show(tab.id);
  }
}

/*
When first loaded, initialize the page action for all tabs.
*/
var gettingAllTabs = browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true});
gettingAllTabs.then((tabs) => {
  for (let tab of tabs) {
    initializePageAction(tab);
  }
});

/*
Each time a tab is updated, reset the page action for that tab.
*/
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((id, changeInfo, tab) => {
  initializePageAction(tab);
});

/*
Toggle title when the page action is clicked.
*/
browser.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(toggleT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the documentation again, and a couple other pages. Browser action and page action open the default.html in a new tab so there is no need to use page action on Android. Also the context menu items at the top of my BG script were causing the BG script to not work on Android.

-- Problem Solved.